# Running separate thread for polling the device and send a keypress event to flash

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sendkeys

I have a windows application in which I have to continuously listen to a device which has buttons on the top and when any of these buttons are pressed I need to send a keypress event to flash.

For implementing this I have following questions:-

•   What is the best way to continuously listen to a device events in a separate thread(to work simultaneously with flash animation)?

•   Can I use timers for this functionality?

•   Finally, how keypress event can be dispatched to flash?

Comment: What kind of device is it? Is it a standard keyboard? Or is it a proprietary device that needs a special driver?

Comment: Sorry for getting back late on this one(Actually I met an accident).
it's an proprietary device. I solved the problem by creating separate thread using system.timer. 
Thanks All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keypress is an event which shouldn't require a separate thread. The action to be taken once the event takes place - in your case sending some data to flash can be done via a separate thread.